# use of $GLOBALS in php

Tags: php, superglobals

I am new to php so I do not know much about $_GLOBALS. I expect these are used to access global variables anywhere. So, my question is what is the problem inside function `addition()`, why I cannot do this? Can't I directly assign a value to the variable z.

```
    <?php 
    $x = 75; 
    $y = 25;

    function addition () { 
        $z = $GLOBALS['x'] + $GLOBALS['y']; 
    }

    addition(); 
    echo $z; 
    ?>
```

I get following error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: z in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\first.php on line 14
```

which is `echo $z;`

Comment: Please learn more about variable scope; See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16959576/3933332

Comment: `$z` is defined only in the function's scope, aka `$z` is not a global. When you're trying to echo out `$z` php will throw an error since it has no knowledge of `$z`  outside of the function's scope. This is, however, a simple fix, just `return $z` and assign the function to a variable: `$variable = addition()` and you'll get the value of `$z` assigned to the variable `$variable`.

Comment: @Andrew is this the only way to get the value of a variable defined inside a function ?? I can not get the value of $z outside function using $GLOBALS['z'] since it is not a global ??

Comment: Check out @Robert 's answer, but skip the Dependency Injection part, get the basics down first.

Comment: There are many ways to pass value from function reference, globals, singleton, values but IMO globals and singleton are the ugliest solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start with programming I can highly recommend you not to use GLOBALS. 
There are better ways to get object/variable than globals. For example [dependency injection](http://fabien.potencier.org/what-is-dependency-injection.html)

Function is something what takes arguments does something with them and return value. So you can create addition function

```
function addition ($x, $y) {
  return $x + $y;
}
```

when invoked this will return sum of $x and $y. When you have this value you can for example output it to user with `echo`

```
echo addition(5, 4);
```

or

```
 $z = addition(5, 4);
 echo $z;
```

In your case you get notice because you want to get variables that are not set. You can check if variable is set with function `isset($variable)`

If you still want to use $_GLOBALS then you need to know what $_GLOBALS is. It's reference for all variables in global scope so to make it work you should write something like

```
$x = 5;
$y = 7;

function addition() { 
    return  $GLOBALS['x'] + $GLOBALS['y']; 
}

echo addition();
```

But this is bad approach and I better don't do it.

**Edit:**

Check also [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: why does this works ?

`<?php 
$x = 75; 
$y = 25;
 
function addition() { 
    $GLOBALS['z'] = $GLOBALS['x'] + $GLOBALS['y']; 
}
 
addition(); 
echo $z; 
?>`

Comment: This is pretty hard to explain but it looks like if you assign key to $_GLOBALS it creates variable and saves reference to this variable. So $_GLOBALS['z'] returns referenced variable where you change value of this variable and you have access to this variable outside function scope

Answer (score 0):

$GLOBALS is a superglobal variable which is used to access all defined variables according to their scope.
In above scenario $z is variable defined within function hence its scope is limited to the function .
To make it globally accessible it should be declared outside function body and should be declared as global variable within function body.

**Example**

```
$z=0;$x=20;$y=30;
function addition() { 
    global $z;
    $z = $GLOBALS['x'] + $GLOBALS['y']; 
}

addition(); 
echo $z;
```

Comment: why does this code works
        <?php 
        $x = 75; 
        $y = 25;
 
        function addition() { 
              $GLOBALS['z'] = $GLOBALS['x'] + $GLOBALS['y']; 
}
 
         addition(); 
         echo $z; 
         ?>